# phpmyAdmin shows list of folder instead of browser page

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I tried access localhost/phpmyadmin, getting list of folders as shown below

[image]

I have installed PHP7.4, Apache2 and phpmyAdmin5.1
OS- MacOs Catalina

DirectoryIndex Index.php Index.html available in /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which I just fixed.

**Server version: Apache/2.4.53 (Unix)
PHP 8.1.6

phpMyAdmin Version: 5.2.0

macOS Monterey 12.4**

Since [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.php) is not bundled anymore with macOS starting from Monterey,
I've installed php and PhpMyAdmin through **homebrew**.

So from the same situation, I modified httpd.conf file:

1. DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
2. uncomment the lines below

```
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

3. added (might change depending on your php version)

```
LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/moduleslibphp.so

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
```

Then  restarted *apache* and launched `http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php`(depends on your port) and it was all good.

Considering your version of php, I think [this](https://wpbeaches.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-11-big-sur-and-earlier-macos/) might be a good help. Good luck!